# Technical term for the visualization of an audio track?

Tags: audio, daw, waveform

What's the technical term for the visualization of an audio track as used in music production software? This image shows what I mean: http://alisocreek.net/vo-article-graphics/Sound_Wave.jpg The image is titled sound wave but isn't there a more precise term referring to the diagram itself?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's called a "waveform" or, when it's zoomed out like that and not showing all the detail, it's more correctly called a "waveform overview".